# 'Missing draft message' in Javascript

Tags: javascript, gmail-api, draftjs

I am working on this issue from last 3 days. I dived through the stack overflow, but of no use. There are the questions about "Missing draft message", but I am still getting this message. I have tried all the ways they have said. but I am still here.
Here is my code

```
const str = "My Draft";
  const msgBody = btoa(str);
 
var token = localStorage.getItem("accessToken");

fetch(
  "https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/drafts?key=[my api key] HTTP/1.1", 
  {
    
    method:"post",
    ContentType: 'application/json',
    Accept: 'application/json',
        headers: {
            
        "Authorization": `Bearer ${token}`,
        
    },
        message: {
            raw: msgBody
          }
  }
)
  .then((data) => data.json())
  .then((response) => console.log(response));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please add message in body https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#supplying_request_options

```
const str = "My Draft";
const msgBody = btoa(str);
 
var token = localStorage.getItem("accessToken");

fetch(
  "https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/drafts?key=[my api key] HTTP/1.1", 
  {
    method: 'POST',
    ContentType: 'application/json',
    Accept: 'application/json',
    headers: {
        "Authorization": `Bearer ${token}`,
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({ // Here changed 
        message: {
            raw: msgBody
        }
    }),
  }
)
  .then((data) => data.json())
  .then((response) => console.log(response));
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It's working now. But it does not showing anyting. Here is snapshot, you can check what is the output for above code..
How to add email, subject and body there??
Here is link for screenshot
https://ibb.co/m0kYjSM

Comment: @MuzammilZafar i think you need to check what body object that API accepts, by adding correct body object you can fix this

Comment: @MuzammilZafar please check documentation for gmail drafts